# SSL v3 Handshake Failure (but only in newer versions of OpenSSL)

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssl, openssl, python-requests

This basic snippet in Python 3.5, with a specific website, fails with `requests.exceptions.SSLError: [SSL: SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE] sslv3 alert handshake failure (_ssl.c:720)`

```
import requests
requests.get("https://ssbp.mycampus.ca/prod_uoit/bwskfshd.P_CrseSchdDetl")
```

It works perfectly fine on Ubuntu 16.04 , but the exact same script with the same versions of all its Python dependencies fails on Debian Stretch.

I've tried installing `requests[security]` and it makes no difference.
The only notable difference between my installations is that Debian has `OpenSSL 1.1.0c  10 Nov 2016` and Ubuntu has version `OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016`.

Somehow the newer version of OpenSSL must be causing it to fail.

The version of `requests` used is `2.11.1`.

Comment: There are changes to the supported ciphers and which are enabled by default and it might also trigger bugs in the specific sites. More can be said only if you provide the URL in question.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I've edited the URL into the original post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The server [only supports](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=ssbp.mycampus.ca) a single old cipher: DES-CBC3-SHA. This cipher is considered weak ([SWEET32](https://sweet32.info/)) and is removed from the default build in OpenSSL 1.1.0. Since Debian follows the default build the cipher is not available on newer Debian versions.

From [Changes between 1.0.2h and 1.1.0](https://www.openssl.org/news/changelog.html#x4):

> To mitigate the SWEET32 attack (CVE-2016-2183), 3DES cipher suites
>        have been disabled by default and removed from DEFAULT, just like RC4.
>        See the RC4 item below to re-enable both.
>        ...
>        RC4 based libssl ciphersuites are now classed as "weak" ciphers and are
>        disabled by default. **They can be re-enabled using the
>        enable-weak-ssl-ciphers option to Configure.**

Comment: The `enable-weak-ssl-ciphers` option worked perfectly, and I notified the site admin that their site is insecure. Thanks!