# Nginx allow cipher TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA

Tags: ssl, nginx, ssl-certificate

I want to allow this cipher TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA on my server to be compliant with NIST guidelines, i put this on my nginx.conf:

```
ssl_ciphers 'DES-CBC3-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:AES:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!RC4:!MD5:!PSK:!aECDH';
```

I thought that i had to put 'DES-CBC3-SHA' but it's still not enabled for TLSv1.1 and TLS1.0

How can i do this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You OpenSSL version is unknown. But if you use OpenSSL 1.1.0 then this cipher is not compiled in by default because it is considered broken. You would need to have a custom build of OpenSSL to use this cipher. For more details see [SSL v3 Handshake Failure (but only in newer versions of OpenSSL)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41584975/ssl-v3-handshake-failure-but-only-in-newer-versions-of-openssl).

Even if you really want to use this broken cipher you should only add it at the end of your cipher string so that all these other and more secure ciphers get preferred and DES-CBC3-SHA gets only used as the (weak) fallback.